# Prestashop: How i can to develop website without effect the online store

Tags: html, css, templates, prestashop

Did i can to develop my website without effect the online Prestashop store?
Because i want to make change on the template store like ".tpl" files and css and javascript but i don't want this change effect the online store.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this :
- Easy but imperfect : Make a copy of your website somewhere, modify whatever you want and then copy the files if you didn't modify the database.
- Advanced but needs time : Learn to use Git (https://try.github.io/) to deploy code modern style.

Comment: Is there a way to get some dev url you can see changes at it when the cache is enabled?

Comment: Actually this is not an option on Prestashop (as it can be, for instance, in Symfony).
You really should clone your website somewhere else (maybe on your own computer with WAMP or XAMP), do your modifications and then copy the modified files to the "production" shop.
This is the only way to insure not destroying everything ...